# How to connect to my remote MySQL database from my Heroku NodeJS app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have a NodeJs backend hosted on Heroku. I am trying to connect to my remote MySQL database that is hosted under my Hostwinds plan. When I tried to connect to the DB in my local environment it worked perfectly, but when I deployed my app to Heroku I get an error saying `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'myUserName'@'someRandomIP' (using password: YES)`.

I have added my Heroku URL to my remote access pannel in cPanel, but that didn't give the user access. I have also tried to add the `someRandomIP` to the remote access pannel in cPanel, but the weird thing about that IP is that is changes on every deploy/re-deploy. I am positive that my connection string is correct, but just in case: `mysql://username:password@ipOfHost/dbName`.

Here is my serverside code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("MySQL");
const { resolve } = require("path");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_API_KEY);

// enable CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}))

// form connection object
var connection = mysql.createConnection(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

// connect to the database
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("You are connected to the database");
})

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Node server listening on oneline-backend.herokuapp.com'));
```

Here is a link to the full error in the Heroku Console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SveGe.png

Any help would be appreciated! This has caused quite a bit of trouble.